# Editing Transactional Emails

Tags: css, transactional, transactional-mail, scss

My transactional emails have a blue background near the top that I would like to change.

As I understand it, it's using SCSS files but I can only see things like `$c-email-background;` in those files.

Where do I make these changes?

Comment: Which magento version?

Answer (score 3):

You can edit your transactional emails templates in the backend at:

**System -> Transactional Emails**

In addition to modifying the content, you have the possibility to change the template style. Either it is to change in content area itself or in the template style area...

Hope that helps.

Comment: What about the location of the ordered items "{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}" etc? How do you edit the table of ordered items? My template has funky things like total being on top instead of bottom.